# tqdm_notebook description is truncated

Tags: tqdm

I am using `tqdm_notebook` to show progress, and update the description to track the loss with the number of iterations.  How can I make the description not be truncated (an image attached below).

I define `ebar = tqdm_notebook(range(NUM_EPOCHS))` and update the description using:

```
ebar.set_description('c_loss: {:.5f}, r_loss: {:.5f}, v_loss: {:.5F}'.format(av_class_loss,
                                                                             av_recon_loss,
                                                                             av_valid_loss))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching on this problem recently, and luckily it has actually been solved in tqdm since version 4.28.1, which is [available on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/4.28.1/)

See [this commit](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/commit/d9973984c5d2becb5bcb8c5930b8a72780b4ca8d) for reference

Namely, the progress bar is a widget from `ipywidgets` that has a dedicated progress bar widget which cannot officially change size. See [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Description) for more information about widget description

Now, it seems that your description is quite long, and setting description length to 'initial' might make you end up with a 1px wide progress bar.

If you need to get a bigger progress bar, the easiest way it display it in two lines, with a Label widget, and change its value directly

```py
from ipywidgets import HBox, Label, IntProgress
import time
from IPython.display import display
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
a = Label('A too long description')
display(a)
b = tqdm(range(100))
for i in b:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    a.value = 'a too long descriptio' + 'o'*i +'n'
```

If you really need to get everything in one line, you can modify tqdm's code [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/_tqdm_notebook.py#L122) so that tqdm widgets is a Hbox with text, IntProgres, text again.

```py
ptext = HTML()
pdesc = HTML()
container = HBox(children=[pdesc, pbar, ptext])
```

Once it's done, you can update the description in the same manner as [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/_tqdm_notebook.py#L161-L164)
but [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/_tqdm_notebook.py#L182-L184) for description