# `tqdm` line is truncated in update

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I'm using the tqdm.trange` function in my project, and update it each epoch, as may be seen in the following code:

```
from tqdm import trange
import time

dec_num = 0.123456
epochs = 10
epoch_progress_bar = trange(10, position=0, leave=True)
for epoch in epoch_progress_bar:
    epoch_progress_bar.set_description(f'|Train| loss: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f}, AUC: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f} |Val| loss: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f}, AUC: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f} | ES: {epoch}/{epochs} | CUDA |')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

in the following image, it appears that the progress bar is not updated properly, and is truncated, while there is plenty room on the right for even a bigger message to be shown:
[image]

**My attempts for solution:**

- I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052686/tqdm-notebook-description-is-truncated) about the same issue, but the solution in it did not work for me, because when I use it - the progress bar is printed on the new line each time the update to the label occurs, as may be seen in the following code and its' output:

**Code:**

```
from ipywidgets import HBox, Label, IntProgress
import time
from IPython.display import display
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

a = Label('A too long description')
display(a)
dec_num = 0.123456
epochs = 10
b = tqdm(range(epochs ))
for i in b:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    display(a)
    a.value = f'|Train| loss: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f}, AUC: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f} |Val| loss: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f}, AUC: {dec_num:.4f}+/-{dec_num:.4f} | ES: {epoch}/{epochs} | CUDA |'
```

**Output:**

```
Label(value='A too long description')
HBox(children=(HTML(value=''), FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=10.0), HTML(value='')))
Label(value='A too long description')
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
Label(value='|Train| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.1235 |Val| loss: 0.1235+/-0.1235, AUC: 0.1235+/-0.…
```

As may be seen - the progress bar doesn't even show, and the label is printed over and over on the new line.

**Desired outcome:**
The desired outcome will be to see both a long update line and the progress of the routine without it being printed on a separate line on each update.

Thanks in advance.